# Is this a php bug

Tags: php

why this code has error (Notice: Use of undefined constant ‍‍ - assumed '‍‍' on line 5)

```
<?
$arr1 = array(
">",
"<",‍‍
);

foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Remove the last ',' at the end of `"<"`. It's your bug.

Comment: @Pushpesh Trailing commas are valid.

Comment: What is the version of PHP you are using? You can get that using `phpinfo()`.

Comment: @Kolink Oh!, didn't know that. Thanks for the info. Btw, when i copied this into a local page, i got characters like `??` at the end of last comma which threw an error.

Comment: thanks i find my answer has a extra control character after comma (cannot see but is exist)

Comment: @saeedarabsheybani Your code has some non-readable characters.

Comment: Good job tackling many those who think trailing commas in array() is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug. You have "non printable chars" in your code at that specific lines, that's why you get a notice. See image, vi never lies! :P

[image]

Delete your code and rewrite it from scratch (no copy/paste) and it will work

Answer (score 3):

Read this in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/function.array):

> *“Having a trailing comma after the last defined array entry, while unusual, is a valid syntax.”*

```
<?php
    $my_array = array('foo', 'bar', 'bat',);
?>
```

But, depending on the version of PHP you are using, it might be invalid. It is better to remove the trailing commas, if the array is static and can be changed, by hand, and not those kind which are generated by `eval()` and other codes.

So, the code for you would be:

```
<?
$arr1 = array(
    ">",
    "<" // Removing the trailing comma.
);

foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

But something which strikes me is, what is the version of PHP you are using? Coz, all the decent versions (PHP 5, 6) have a tolerance to one trailing comma.

And also, you must check for **UTF-8 BOM** characters in your code. I generally use CuteFTP's editor to check them, or even a Hex Editor does the job well. When I copied your code and pasted it, I saw two characters here, see the screenshot:

[image]

And that's what was causing the problem. Remove them and your code is good.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of PHP, your code is valid. Unfortunately for you, your version does not support trailing commas, so you will just need to remove it like so:

```
<?
$arr1 = array(
    ">",
    "<"
);

foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that there are two invisible characters (called [zero width joiner](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm) character, hex `E2 80 8D`) after the last comma in the array.

Copy and paste the code from your example into a text editor, put your cursor in-front of the last comma, and then hit the left arrow key a few times. The cursor should stand still.

I am not quite sure why this has happened, but fixing it should be as simple as removing them:

```
$arr1 = array('>', '<');
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the error is the comma in your Array. Try this:

```
<?
$arr1 = array(
">",
"<"
);

foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Trailing commas are valid.

Answer (score -1):

@Pushpesh  i think there is no issue with using , at the end of array
look at this http://codepad.org/oUj8PwY2